# Why does .pam_environment not include $HOME in my new path?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, pam

I created a `/home/myname/.pam_environment` [file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4-.2F.pam_environment) containing

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/apps/flyway
```

But my new path doesn't end with `/home/myname/apps/flyway`. Why not?

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/apps/flyway
```

Comment: Presumably `HOME` is set after `pam_env` does its job. Looking at http://superuser.com/a/271935/334516, that may be the case.

Comment: But my syntax, including the ${HOME} part, comes directly from the manual (linked in my question above). Surely Ubuntu wouldn't include it if it loaded afterwards.

Comment: That's a community wiki - practically anyone can edit it. Presumably whoever added it made a mistake. A quick debug run of `pam_env` shows no signs of `$HOME`. (The syntax is correct, you just need to set `HOME` manually before using it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is apparently [an *old* issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=109281) (as in 15 years old). The "fix" at them time was:

```
* Note that HOME may not be useful in pam_environment, closes: #109281
```

[The Linux PAM site](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) also says as much:

> Note that many environment variables that you would like to use may
>   not be set by the time the module is called. For example, HOME is used
>   below several times, but many PAM applications don't make it available
>   by the time you need it.

Apparently, someone bothered to [patch `pam_env` for it](https://fedorahosted.org/linux-pam/ticket/24) over on Fedora.

Anyway, on Debian-based systems, a crude way is to use:

```
HOME=/home/@{PAM_USER}
```

Before referencing `${HOME}`. This could be done in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, for example. Of course, this will break where the user's home directory is not `/home/$USER`.

Answer (score 7):

As of PAM version 1.2.0, you can use `@{HOME}` instead of `${HOME}` and it will work consistently:
https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/commit/73bdfac8c091492f466342feb8f2f5daa2f4c39b